# Termination of mutually recursive functions using the Maybe monad

Tags: haskell, recursion, lazy-evaluation, option-type

Below is are two examples of mutually recursive function pairs. The first example terminates and produces the expected result. The second example is similar, except it uses the Maybe monad. fun1' does not terminate when called.

```
fun1 = 1 + fun2
fun2 = let x = fun1 
       in  2
-- terminates. result is 3.

fun1' = do a <- Just 1 
           b <- fun2'
           return $ a + b
fun2' = do x <- fun1'
           return 2
-- does not terminate.
```

Here are another two examples. Once again, the first example terminates with the expected result and the second example (using the Maybe monad) does not terminate.

```
fun1'' = fun2'' : [1]
fun2'' = (head . tail $ fun1'') + 1 
-- terminates. result is [2,1]

fun1''' = do a <- Just [1]
             b <- fun2'''
             return $ b : a              
fun2''' = do x <- fun1'''
             return $ (head . tail $ x) + 1
-- does not terminate.
```

I believe I have a situation that is semantically similar to the last example in my real code. What are my options for getting it to terminate? Will I be forced to abandon the Maybe monad?

**Update**
This is the solution I ended up using;

```
fun1'''' = do a <- Just [1]
              b <- fun2''''
              return $ b : a
fun2'''' = do return $ (head . tail . fromJust $ fun1'''') + 1
-- terminates :)
```

The key difference is that `fun2''''` no longer operates on `fun1''''` using the bind operator. Instead it explicitly uses fromJust (and assumes that `fun1''''` is not `Nothing`).

In my real code `fun2` actually calls a number of other functions. These other functions are not mutually recursive with `fun2`, and can potentially return a Nothing result. Fortunately I can still use the bind operator implicitly within the do notation for accessing the other required values.

Answer (score 4):

The reason that `fun1'/fun2'` do not terminate is that the `Maybe` monad's bind operation (`>>=`) needs to check if the first argument is `Nothing` or if it is `Just (...)`. So when you do `x <- fun1'` in `fun2'`, even though you do not use `x`, you still need to check if `fun1'` is `Nothing` or `Just (...)` (you don't care about the (...), it would be bound to `x` which you don't use anyway). But to check that, you need to know if `fun2'` is `Just` or `Nothing`, because you're binding b to the result of it in `fun1'` (`b <- fun2'`) -> infinite recursion.

The same doesn't happen in the first case, because in `fun2`, you don't use `x`, so `fun1` never needs to be evaluated!

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that your terminating function `fun1` is not mutually exclusive even though that appears to be.
Infact, your `fun2'` function actually just refers to the value `2`. Example:

```
λ> let x = undefined in 2
2
```

The `undefined` part doesn't get evaluated at all. Hence your `x = fun1` will not at all be evaluated in your `fun2` function and therefore it terminates successfully since `fun2` evaluates to `2`.

Whereas in your `fun2'` example it doesn't get reduced to any value. So, it doesn't terminate. Infact, if you actually turn your `fun2'` function into let expression just like your `fun2` example then it will terminate:

```
fun2' = let x = fun1'
        in (Just 2)
```

`fun2''` is a mutually recursive function which refers to value `2`:

```
λ> tail fun1''
[1]
λ> head $ tail fun1''
1
λ> (head $ tail fun1'') + 1
2
```

So `fun2''` actually refers to a value `2`.

Comment: Ok, I see what you are saying about fun1/fun2 not actually being mutually recursive. This makes sense, since fun1 does not actually need to use fun2 to produce its result. However, I would have thought that fun1''/fun2'' could be considered mutually recursive, since neither can produce its result without the other.

Comment: @knick Yes, you are correct. Updated it appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have no choice but to abandon the Maybe monad.

Remember that monads just represent sequences of computations that can be chained together. The `Maybe` monad represents computations that can fail and when one of the computations in the sequence fails, we get a `Nothing` in the end. Though it looks like the value of `x` is not required (and hence we expect a program halt due to lazy valuation) for the end result, it is in a sequence, and hence has to be evaluated  resulting in an infinite recursion.

Instead try this:

```
fun1' = do a <- Just 1 
           b <- fun2'
           return $ a + b
fun2' = do Nothing
           fun1'
           return 2
main = print $ fun1'
```

This will stop because, the `Nothing` will bypass all other computations.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a need to combine the `Maybe` monad with mutual recursion, then perhaps you want [`RecursiveDo` notation](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.8.3/html/users_guide/syntax-extns.html#recursive-do-notation), which allows monadically calculated values inside an `mdo` block to refer recursively to each other (for monads supporting the `MonadFix` class).  The following compiles and gives the result `Just ([2,1],2)` that you probably would expect.

```
{-# LANGUAGE RecursiveDo #-}

maybeFuns = mdo
    fun1''' <- do a <- Just [1]
                  return $ fun2''' : a              
    fun2''' <- return $ (head . tail $ fun1''') + 1
    return (fun1''', fun2''')
```

You need to define it in one `mdo` block rather as separate functions, though. Although you *could* replace `maybeFuns =` by `Just (fun1''', fun2''') =` if you don't care about getting an error if some part evaluates to `Nothing`.